# How to access computed properties in a child controller from a parent resource

Tags: ember.js

Say I have routes like

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('month', { path: '/:month_id' }, function() {
        this.route('summary');
    });
});
```

I would think for the `/:month_id/summary` route, the default model/controller would be the same as for the `/:month_id` route, so I'd have access to the correct `month` model and any computed properties I added to my `MonthsController`. Instead, I find I have to add this code:

```
App.MonthSummaryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor("month");
    }
});

App.MonthSummaryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     needs: ['month']
});
```

This seems like a lot to do to get my URLs to point to the same data, especially since I plan on making many child URLS of this resource that will be sharing data.

Is there a better way to do this? I just want to make sure I'm dong it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since using the `needs` API is the correct and recommended way to share data beetween controllers you are on the right track.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems like it makes it difficult to have isolated views. I'd like to have a view that is independent of which route/controller it is rendered in, but with this my data will change, maybe `this.get('controller.controllers.month')`, maybe something else.

Comment: Maybe I need to look more into `render` and `control`, since I'm just doing views.